# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 when running a migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, migration, rake

I get an `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error when running a migration with rake in ruby on rails (version 3.1).

The code for my migration can be found below.

Thanks!

```
class ChangePhoneToString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :restaurants, :phone
    remove_column :restaurants, :price 
    add_column    :restaurants, :phone, :string
    add_column    :restaurants, :price, :string

  end

  def down
    remove_column :restaurants, :phone
    remove_column :restaurants, :price
    add_column    :restaurants, :phone, :integer
    add_column    :restaurants, :price, :integer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is slight change in the migration file in rails 3.1.
Currently remove_column is not supported in rails 3.1
Please read the [rail 3.1 migration documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#writing-your-change-method) here

Comment: Is this still valid? The migration documentation mentions remove_column as a valid command. I've used it with previous migrations. I'm getting the same error, however as above- possibly for other reasons.